# Is there a way to run a function asynchronous with the rest of the page from inside of a jquery success function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So I have a webpage that loads a list of content from a php server-side script, sorts it on the client side and adds the final list to a div in the webpage. When  loading the page a button press pulls up the list something like

```
  searchRequest = $.ajax(
  {
        type: "GET",
        // blah blah blah 
        async: true,
        success: function(data)
        {
              sortTheData(data)
              addTheDataToThePage(data)


        }
  });
```

After a bit of testing I figured out that the jquery ajax request was working async as it was supposed to, but the page was still hanging during loading while sorting the list.

What I want to do is have the sorting and adding functions in the success function start at that point, but run without blocking the rest of the page from running smoothly (ie in its own thread, but still adding its results to the page at the end).

Ive tried running the sort & add parts in an async function, as well as wrapping it in a promise return, but the page still seems to hang whenever it reaches the sorting stage.

Do I need to use some sort of Web Worker to do this, or is there a way of doing it in pure javascript?

Comment: It looks like your sorting function is doing some complex calculations, if your page was hanging. It is possible to run a Web Worker (by WebWorker API) after your request responded successfully and sort this data inside it.

Comment: How do the times taken to execute `sortTheData` and `addTheDataToThePage` compare? Speeding up the sort or  offloading it to another thread won't help if the bottleneck is in updating and rendering the DOM changes.. Sharing the code for ``addTheDataToThePage`  may also help - there are known _bad_ ways to update the DOM with lots of additions.

Comment: @traktor I dont have hard evidence, but watching the console log calls the addTheDataToThePage call seems minimal compared to the sorting. I got the web worker working nicely for the sorting, but theres still a bit of a hitch with the content append to page function, so Im going to set that up to load the first 10, then load the rest on page scroll sort of thing

Comment: As previously commented, there are slow ways to update the DOM, such as using multiple calls to append HTML to an element instead of using `insertAdjacentHTML`. Generating tables of thousands of lines without fixed column widths can slow things down as well. Please edit the question to share the code  that updates the DOM if you want further feedback.